# Is $({F^{\times})^{ diag}}\backslash(GL_2 \times E^{\times})_{det=\mathbb{N}}$ a unitary group?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, p-adic-groups

Let $F$ be an p-adic field, and $E$ be a quadratic extension of $F$, then is $({F^{\times})^{ diag}}\backslash(GL_2 \times E^{\times})_{det=\mathbb{N}}$ isomorphic to some unitary group $U_{E/F}(2)$? Here, $\mathbb{N}(e)=e *\sigma(e)$, where $\sigma$ is the nontrivial element in $Gal(E/F)$. And $(GL_2 \times E^{\times})_{det=\mathbb{N}} :=\{(g,e)\in GL_2 \times E^{\times}|det(g)=\mathbb{N}(e)\}$.

Comment: Can you explain the notation ${\rm det}={\mathbb N}$?

Comment: Does "det=\mathbb N" mean that the determinant is a norm, by any chance?

Comment: Also, I think $U_{E/F}(2)$ is not reliably universal notation. I'm guessing that you mean the hermitian form to be two diagonal 1's, and conjugation is Galois conjugation?

Comment: I have edited the problem again.

Comment: The answer depends on whether  you regard $({F^{\times})^{ diag}}\backslash(GL_2 \times E^{\times})_{det=\mathbb{N}}$ as an algebraic group over $F$ or as a topological group (the group of points).

Comment: I will write details tomorrow.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi As topological group, I think. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Cooler Panda and Paul Garrett. The rank of the algebraic group $U_{E/F}(2)$ is equal to the Witt index  of the hermitian form. On the other hand the rank of    $(F^\times )^{\rm diag} \backslash ({\rm GL}_2 \times E^\times )_{{\rm det}=N_{E/F}}$ is $1$ ($2$ for ${\rm GL}_2$ + $1$ for $E^\times$ -$1$ for the relation $-1$ for $F^\times$). So the isomorphism has a chance to hold  only if the Witt index of the form is  $1$: the hermitien space is the direct sum of two isotropic lines. So one must as well  assume that the matrix of the form is the antidiagonal $(1,1)$.

Comment: @Cooler Panda and Paul Garrett Cont'd. Working with the antidiagonal matrix is then much easier and you can solve the equation of the group by brute force.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer this question for now. However, I have made some relevant calculations that are too long for a comment.

We set
$$G_0=(GL_2 \times E^{\times})_{{\rm det}={\rm Nm}}\,,\quad G_1=G_0/(F^\times)^{\rm diag},\quad G_2=U_{E/F}(1,-\lambda),$$
where $\lambda\in F^\times$ and  $U_{E/F}(1,-\lambda)$ denotes the unitary group of the diagonal  hermitian form
$$h(z_1,z_2)={\rm Nm}(z_1)-\lambda{\rm Nm}(z_2).$$

We wish to know whether $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic.
If $\lambda\notin{\rm im}({\rm Nm})$, then the hermitian form $h$ does not represent 0, the topological group $G_2$ is compact, and hence, it is not isomorphic to the noncompact group $G_1$
(this has been already noticed by Paul Broussous).
Therefore, let us assume that $\lambda\in{\rm im}({\rm Nm})$; then we may assume that $\lambda=1$ and $G_2=U_{E/F}(1,-1)$.

Consider the homomorphism
$$\alpha\colon G_0\to F^\times,\quad (g,e)\mapsto {\rm Nm}(e).$$
Clearly, ${\rm im}(\alpha)={\rm im}({\rm Nm})\subset F^\times$.
The homomorphism $\alpha$ induces a homomorphism
$$\beta\colon G_1\to F^\times/F^{\times\,2},$$
and we have
$${\rm im}(\beta)= {\rm im}({\rm Nm})/F^{\times\,2}.$$
We set
$$U_1=\{e\in E\ |\ {\rm Nm}(e)=1\}.$$

We have a canonical homomorphism
$$\gamma\colon{\rm SL}(2,F)\times U_1\to G_1\quad (g,e)\mapsto [g,e],$$
where $[g,e]$ denotes the class of the pair $(g,e)\in G_0$.
Then
$$\ker(\gamma)=\{\pm 1\},\quad {\rm im}(\gamma)=\ker(\beta).$$
Thus we obtain a short exact sequence
$$1\to ({\rm SL}(2,F)\times U_1)/\{\pm 1\}\to G_1\to {\rm im}({\rm Nm})/F^{\times\,2}\to 1.$$

On the other hand, we have a canonical homomorphism
$$\delta\colon {{\rm SU}_{E/F}}(1,-1)\times U_1\to G_2 \quad (s,e)\mapsto se,$$
whose kernel is $\{\pm 1\}$ and whose cokernel is $U_1/U_1^2$, where we write $U_1^2$ for the subgroup of squares in $U_1$.
Thus we obtain a  short exact sequence
$$ 1\to({{\rm SU}_{E/F}}(1,-1)\times U_1)/\{\pm 1\}\to G_2\to U_1/U_1^2\to 1.$$
We have ${{\rm SU}_{E/F}}(1,-1)\simeq{\rm SL}(2,F)$  (see, for instance, the book on classical groups by Jean Dieudonné or the book Geometric Algebra by Emil Artin).
Thus we obtain a short exact sequence
$$ 1\to({\rm SL}(2,F)\times U_1)/\{\pm 1\}\to G_2\to U_1/U_1^2\to 1.$$

Comparing the short exact sequences for $G_1$ and for $G_2$, we see that *if the 2-groups ${\rm im}({\rm Nm})/F^{\times\,2}$ and $U_1/U_1^2$ are non-isomorphic* (that is, have different orders),
then $G_1$ and $G_2$ are not isomorphic "in a nice way".

I do not know whether the 2-groups ${\rm im}({\rm Nm})/F^{\times\,2}$ and $U_1/U_1^2$ are isomorphic or not. I suggest for OP to ask this on MathOverflow.